# How to set This Format like P19001

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to like this P19001, P19002, P19003... 
I have some code

```
 $p="P";
 $increment_id=1; //fatch from databse last id
 $const=0001;
 $year= substr(date("Y"),2); 
 echo $p."".$year."".$const+$increment_id;
```

but I get this like P191

Comment: use `$year = date("y")` and as per your example `$const=0001;` should be `$const=001;`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I want 4 digit

Comment: then why in sample output you added `002`, `003` etc after `19` ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra not working this already try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to have the last part zero padded, you need to add formatting to that as it is a number (and 2 is the same as 0002).

As the easiest way is to use [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) - you can combine them all with...

```
echo sprintf("%s%s%04d", $p, $year, $const+$increment_id);
```

The manual explains what the various components are.

Answer (score 0):

This code is work efficiently

```
 $result = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'table_number'");
 $p = "P";
 $increment_id = $result->result()[0]->Auto_increment;
 $year = substr(date("Y"),2); 
 $data['pNumber'] = sprintf("%s%s%04d", $p, $year,$increment_id);
```